# Difference between ember and glimmer

Tags: ember.js, glimmer.js

I want to know the differences in ember and glimmer.
I know that glimmer is used for components. But why do we need separate part for component called glimmer?

can anyone explain this in detail?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very shortly, Glimmer is a rendering engine while EmberJS is a framework using this engine (since its certain version). Read about it bit more [here](https://emberjs.com/blog/2016/07/29/announcing-the-glimmer-2-alpha.html) and [here](https://emberjs.com/blog/2017/04/05/emberconf-2017-state-of-the-union.html#toc_introducing-glimmer-js)

Comment: The difference is [explained in the announcement post](https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2017/04/05/emberconf-2017-state-of-the-union.html#toc_introducing-glimmer-js).

Answer (score 4):

Glimmer.js is lightweight library for creating component-based applications while Ember.js is feature-packed framework. You can think of Glimmer.js as View layer of Ember.

In the future you should be able to grab Glimmer.js, and then install your way with dependencies up to Ember.js. For example - you can install Routing from Ember, etc.

Also, Glimmer.js uses TypeScript by default, and its Components are true ES classes. That's why you get better support in editors for writing apps in Glimmer.js.

Similarity between Glimmer.js and Ember.js is that both use Ember CLI for tooling.

Comment: can we use glimmer instead of ember? @Daniel Kmak, what i mean is can ember will be completely replaced by ember

Comment: If your application does not require complex features like Ember Data then you can use Glimmer instead of Ember.